# How to SSH login to Google Cloud Shell using an existing private key on a YubiKey security key

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, google-cloud-shell

I can use `gcloud cloud-shell ssh` to login to Google Cloud Shell.

This, on first use, creates a `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` (+`.pub`).

But I already have existing SSH private key/s, and would much prefer to use those, specifically `ed25519-sk` and `id_ecdsa_sk` ones [backed by a physical YubiKey security key](https://github.com/vorburger/vorburger.ch-Notes/blob/develop/security/ed25519-sk.md). The [gcloud cloud-shell ssh documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/cloud-shell/ssh#--ssh-key-file) mentions a `--ssh-key-file` flag, but it does not appear to work, and prints an `ignored explicit argument` error message that is not particularly helpful:

```
$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 367.0.0
alpha 2021.12.10
beta 2021.12.10
bq 2.0.72
core 2021.12.10
gsutil 5.5

$ gcloud cloud-shell ssh --ssh-key-file=~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
ERROR: (gcloud.cloud-shell.ssh) argument --ssh-key-file: ignored explicit argument '~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk'
Usage: gcloud cloud-shell ssh [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --authorize-session | --command | --dry-run |
                         --force-key-file-overwrite | --help | --ssh-flag |
                         --ssh-key-file
```

I thought perhaps it doesn't dig SK SSH keys, but even a simple good ol' self created RSA does not appear to work:

```
$ ssh-keygen
(...)
Your identification has been saved in /home/vorburger/.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /home/vorburger/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:...

$ gcloud --verbosity=debug cloud-shell ssh --ssh-key-file=~/.ssh/id_rsa --verbosity=debug
ERROR: (gcloud.cloud-shell.ssh) argument --ssh-key-file: ignored explicit argument '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

How does ones use `gcloud cloud-shell ssh` with existing SSH keys?

Comment: "--ssh-key-file: ignored explicit argument..." Do you get the same error if you spell out the full path to the file: "... --ssh-key-file=/home/vorburger/.ssh/id_rsa ..."? Some programs don't treat "~" as anything special.

Comment: @Kenster good idea, I tried that, but it doesn't help - same error message.

Comment: Hmmm, might be that the error you're getting is a different one but the way cloud-shell.ssh has be programmed obscures it. The default path for ssh is `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` (at least according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/cloud-shell/ssh#--ssh-key-file)), so do you get a different error when you place your ssh key there or does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour seems to be a bug in the code of the SDK.

On the file `<gcloud path>/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/cloud_shell/util.py` we can see how the `--ssh-key-file` argument is parsed:

```py
parser.add_argument(
    '--ssh-key-file',
    help="""\
    The path to the SSH key file. By default, this is
      *~/.ssh/google_compute_engine*.
    """,
    action='store_true')
```

That `parser` comes from the [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

In the documentation of that module, we can see what [`store_true` of the `action` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) means:

> - `'store_true'` and `'store_false'` - These are special cases of 'store_const' used for storing the values True and False respectively.

`--ssh-key-file` should probably be a string, so the way it's programmed, it's going to ignore anything that's not a boolean.

I'm guessing the best option in this situation is to raise a bug in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=0), since it's a bug on the SDK. I've done just that, and this is the link to the report: https://issuetracker.google.com/216434260

Meanwhile, the workaround would be to replace `'store_true'` by something that should work, like `'store'`:

> - `'store'` - This just stores the argument’s value. This is the default action.

To do so in your local installation of the SDK, simply execute this `sed` command:

```
sed -zi 's/store_true/store/2' $(gcloud info --format 'value(installation.sdk_root)')/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/cloud_shell/util.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't wish to use `gcloud cloud-shell ssh` after the first time you connect to gcp cloud shell with gcloud, You can later use:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine admin_@IPADDRESS -p 6000
```

...where `IPADDRESS` is the IP Addr of the cloud shell instance. I discovered the address for me by looking in ~/.ssh/known_hosts .

If you use emacs, then you can connect via tramp using this filespec:

```
/ssh:USER@cloudshell#6000:/home/USER
```

In my case, `USER` was `admin_`. This requires that the ~/.ssh/config has a stanza like this:

```
Host cloudshell
  HostName IPADDRESS
  Port 6000
  User admin_
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine
```